# Helm upgrade fails to update the deployment in another EKS cluster

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

**What is the issue**

We have custom JAVA based application which basically updates the ingress entries in another EKS cluster using API layer . Let me explain

1: JAVA application is deployed in POD in one EKS cluster, named , A. This app has logic of setting the context of another EKS cluster, named , B and run few commands to append the ingress entries in deployment using helm package manager.

2: If we run the java app without container / POD , it works fine

3: If we run the java app within POD (using deployment/service) , deployed in cluster A, throws following error. This JAVA app basically executes the `helm.sh` explained below

```
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
```

The Dockerfile as below :

```
FROM openjdk:17-slim

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

RUN apt-get -y update; apt-get -y install curl; apt-get -y install unzip; apt-get -y install jq
RUN curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/main/scripts/get-helm-3
RUN chmod 700 get_helm.sh
RUN ./get_helm.sh

RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
RUN unzip awscliv2.zip && ./aws/install

ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<key>
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<acc-key>
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1

ADD helm.sh /app 
RUN chmod 755 /app/helm.sh
ADD target/app1.jar /app/app1.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/app1.jar" ]
```

The content of shell script (`helm.sh`) is as follows :

```
helm upgrade --install <chartname> <chart-dir> --namespace plat --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config -f <chart-dir>/values.yaml
```

**what we have tried**

1: open all the traffic on the nodes of EKS cluster (incoming/outgoing)

2: configured the service as "NodePort" instead of ClusterIP. It is the same service where we need to append the ingress entries.

3: pass the kubeconfig at command line of that cluster where we need to append the ingress entries

Still no luck

As the error suggests , it is the issue of POD communication across clusters but not getting where we are missing .

Please help / suggest

Comment: You've compromised your AWS credentials by publishing them in clear text in a Docker image.  Is it possible your security team revoked them?  In EKS you should be able to use AWS STS to get credentials for a specific IAM role, and then that role will need AWS permissions to access the other cluster.

Comment: You also will generally need to set up a kubeconfig file specific to EKS, and it needs a specific helper to supply credentials.  Is that file in the right place?  Do you have the necessary credential helper in the image?

Comment: @DavidMaze: Thanks 
The POD where we are running shell script have the kube config file specific to EKS . What is this helper you are talking about ? Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @DavidMaze: Im already setting up the context using aws eks command line 

aws eks --region $2 update-kubeconfig --name $1